# Is this code is a good PHP practice for treat results from my query?

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to know if this is a good practice, having or not a huge result on my query.

When I have few lines everything seems fine (even if this method is not a good practice), but when I have 10,000 rows everything goes crazy (Fatal error: Allowed memory size).

```
abstract class System
{
    public static function arrayOfObjectTo($reference, $rows)
    {
        $response = array();
        foreach($rows as $row) {
            $response[] = new $reference($row)
        }
        return $response;
    }

    public static function arrayOfObjectToJson($rows)
    {
        $response = array();
        foreach ($rows as $object) {
            $response[] = $object->toObject();
        }
        return json_encode($response);
    }
}

class Report
{
    public function __construct($data)
    {
        $this->setName($data['name']);
        $this->setEmail($data['email']);
        $this->setPassword($data['password']);
    }

    public function toObject() 
    {
        $object = new stdClass();
        $object->name = $this->getName();
        $object->email = $this->getEmail();
        $object->password = $this->getPassword();
        return $object;
    }

    // getters and setters ...
}

class ReportModel
{
    public function getAll()
    {
        $this->query('SELECT * FROM ...');
        return System::arrayOfObjectTo('Report', $this->rows);
    }
}

class ReportController
{
    public function show()
    {
        $model = new ReportModel();
        return System::arrayOfObjectToJson($model->getAll());
    }
}
```

The focus on my question is the best way to treat my Report object, verifying data types and others stuffs.

The final result is show to client all the rows treated and formated.

```
[
    { name:"A", email:"a@.com", password:"1" },
    { name:"B", email:"b@.com", password:"2" },
    { name:"C", email:"c@.com", password:"3" }
    ...
]
```

This is only an example. Sometimes I have a BIG query with many columns and rows to be shown.

Comment: What does "go crazy" look like exactly?

Comment: I suspect you'll run out of memory with large result sets. Look into chunking your query to stream results to the client.

Comment: What is that code supposed to do? What's the problem it solves, ultimately? If you need to deliver the contents of entire table to the client, there has to be some sort of reason why, no?

Comment: After your edits, what @ceejayoz said - deliver the rows in chunk, not at once. That means you'll perform multiple requests. Also, showing 10 000 rows to the client? What human is able to read through 10 000 rows?

Comment: What is the point of having a `toObject` function, since it's already an object?

Comment: @php_nub_qq, because I can't convert an specific object to json. Because of the private attrs.

Comment: It looks like you're building your own framework here. What you should do first is evaluate various existing [development frameworks](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) as there's probably one that suits your needs and style. You're making some serious mistakes here with password handling that need to be addressed.

Comment: There is an interface called `jsonSerializable`, it allows for you to implement a method which will determine what to return when the object is json encoded.

Comment: @N.B., got your point. just to be clear the real "client", or the final result is write the rows inside a file.

Comment: Ok, great, it means you're basically building a REST-ful service of a sort. Definitely chunk the response, never just stick the entire contents of the table in the output. You can come up with a small protocol for this - for example, when the "client" asks for the data, check how many rows there are and if they're above X (say, 100) then you can send a response saying that there's Y amount of rows and that the client should be sending offsets (you deliver chunks based on what client asks, exactly what @ceejayoz was referring to).

Comment: I updated my answer a bit, hope that helps.

Comment: @N.B. exactly, an RESTful service. Where many differents queries and objects have the "same kind" of response. Well by all the answers I guess that this structure is a bad idea, i just need to chunk in a better way. All this ideas was really helpful. Thank everyone for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would rework the code a little, rename `ReportModel` to `ReportList` for clarity, then save the results of `getAll` as a property. Implement interface `JsonSerializable` and serialize the object directly. You also have to implement the interface on the `Report` object and specify which fields to return for serialization.

```
class ReportList implements JsonSerializable
{
    protected $reports = array();

    public function getAll()
    {
        $this->query('SELECT * FROM ...');
        $this->reports = System::arrayOfObjectTo('Report', $this->rows);
        return $this;
    }

    public function jsonSerialize(){
        return $this->reports;
    }
}

class Report implements JsonSerializable
{
    public function __construct($data)
    {
        $this->setName($data['name']);
        $this->setEmail($data['email']);
        $this->setPassword($data['password']);
    }

    public function jsonSerialize(){
        return ['name' => $this->name, 'email' => $this->email]; // array of private fields
    }
}
```

Then

```
class ReportController
{
    public function show()
    {
        $model = new ReportList();
        return json_encode($model->getAll());
    }
}
```

Additionally, if you would like some remarks, your code is not really flexible or reliable. You will get all kinds of errors, for example if the value given to the constructor of `Report` is not an array or is an array but does not contain the keys you use. This is not really related to the problem so I'll cut it here, just wanted to let you know. You can probably get better advice regarding this topic on [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Regarding to the error when having many rows, it depends on many things, mainly your machine and php settings. Saying you get this error on 10k rows, you either have really large rows or very low allowed memory settings for php. At average row length of 100 bytes, which is probably a lot more than you would have most of the times, 10k rows of 100 bytes are about 1 Megabyte. I am not very aware of php internals but to convert it to json you are going to need at maximum 5 times the space of the information itself, meaning that you would need 5 Megabytes of memory (in the most extreme case) for the freakishly big json string, adding that original 1 Megabyte of the data itself + something like 200KB that php uses, you end up at no more than 7 - 10 Megabytes of memory for 10k rows at average size of 100 bytes. If your scripts are not allowed to allocate 10 Megabytes of ram, oh well.

Comment: I didn't know about the "implements JsonSerializable", that's it's a really good touch. Thank you for the advice.

Comment: @Pablo yeah, it's quite funny, I found out about it recently as well, and I've been dealing with PHP for years.